# Avoid writing progress bars to file in linux

Tags: linux, bash, stdout

I have a process that prints output, but this output also includes loading bars.

I would like to both write this output to a file and display this output.

Normally I could just do:

`./my_process.sh | tee -a my_log_file.txt`

or

```
./my_process.sh >> my_log_file.txt
tail -f my_log_file.txt
```

This prints everything to my terminal, however it also prints EVERYTHING to the log file, including each step of the progress bar!

I would like to exclude progress bar iterations from getting printed to the log file.

For my purposes, any line with a carriage return can be excluded from the log file. How can I exclude carriage return lines from getting appended to the log file while still printing them to stdout on the terminal?

Comment: @mgoldwasser: you should **edit your question** to tell what other program your script is calling, or perhaps even give the code of your script.

Comment: I guess that the bars are from `wget` (or some `ftp` client) and that is relevant. IIRC, there is some option to disable progress bars in `wget`; so I do believe you should tell which program is your script calling

Comment: @basile-starynkevitch also, disabling the progress bars wouldn't work, because I am still trying to write them to the terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can filter the tee before logging

for example

```
$ echo -e "progress_ignore\r\nlog this\nprogress_ignore\r" | tee >(awk '!/\r/' >> output.log)
progress_ignore
log this
progress_ignore

$ cat output.log
log this
```

Comment: Thanks! Worth mentioning too that if someone needed stderr in the output file, the following alteration might work: `echo -e "progress_ignore\r\nlog this\nprogress_ignore\r" 2>&1 | tee >(awk '!/\r/' >> output.log)`

Comment: How could I `nohup` this?

Comment: For long running programs, making awk interactive helped me. Also in my case, backspaces were handling the progress bar: `$RUN |& tee >(awk -W interactive "!/\b/" >> output.log)`.